# django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(650)

Tags: python, django

I have a model `TextField` that I have recently changed it's `max_length` from 650 to 1500.

```
class Comment(models.Model)
    ...
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have performed makemigrations and migrate, and there are no issues on my local server when I post a comment that is 650+ characters.

However when I post a comment over 650+ characters on my remote server, it returns this error:

```
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/james/postr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(650)
```

even though I've checked the remote code has changed to `max_length=1500`.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I have the idea that you did *not* migrate the database.

Comment: Did you create a migration and migrate your db ?

Comment: Yes all changes are migrated, and I have confirmed the migration file that made the change has successfully migrated to my remote server. However I am still getting the error.

Comment: Ok so the +650 characters comment is actually succesfully created. However it still returns the error, and the error is preventing the ajax upload of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

In my comment creation view, it also creates an `Inbox` object:

```
inbox = Inbox.objects.create(user=post.user, replier=request.user, type='commented', text=ajax_comment, post=post)
```

which has a `max_length` of 650...

I've now changed it to:

```
class Inbox(models.Model)
    ...
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
```

and it's now working.